# Storybook Angular cannot resolve parameters on base class

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I am in the process of adding storybook into an existing app. Apart from a few painful issue which are now behind me, it's been mostly a success, however I have encountered a new issue.
I have multiple components which extend from an abstract base class which are complaining they cannot resolve parameters for. EG: `Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

This component doesn't have a constructor, but the base class which it extends does, and has 7 params which matches the 7 question marks.
I have provided classes for storybook to use through `moduleMetadata`, which worked for other components which have their own constructor, but isn't working for these one.

If I had a fake constructor to just pass the params to super() it then works, but I don't want to have to add this pointless constructor in for all such components.

Below is a very stripped example of the code.

Story file:

```js
export default {
  title: 'My Stories',
  component: MyComponent,
  decorators: [
    withKnobs,
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [
        // Import some modules needed here
      ],
      providers: [
        // I pass in all my services here, these are the 7 params needed for the component's base class
      ],
      declarations: [
        // Required child components are here
      ],
    }),
  ],
};

export const ComponentStory = () => ({
  component: MyComponent,
  props: {},
});
```

Component file:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent {
  //Implementation here - No constructor
}
```

Base Component file:

```js
export abstract class BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    protected firstService: FirstService,
    protected router: Router,
    protected ngProgress: NgProgress,
    protected secondService: SecondService,
    protected thirdService: ThirdService,
    protected forthService: ForthService,
    public fifthService: FifthService
  ) {
    // Some other code here
  }

  // Implementation...
}
```

With the above, I get the error regarding unresolved parameters.
If, however I add the below into the component file, it then works just fine and mounts the component into storybook as expected:

```js
  constructor(
    protected firstService: FirstService,
    protected router: Router,
    protected ngProgress: NgProgress,
    protected secondService: SecondService,
    protected thirdService: ThirdService,
    protected forthService: ForthService,
    public fifthService: FifthService
  ) {
    super(
      firstService,
      router,
      ngProgress,
      secondService,
      thirdService,
      forthService,
      fifthService
    );
  }
```

However, as you can imagine, I do not want to have to add a pointless constructor to all these components which extend this base class without their own constructor just for the sake of storybook.

Can anybody suggest what else I could try, or what I might be missing?
Many thanks.

**tl:dr**
Component in storybook cannot resolve parameters for abstract base class unless I add a constructor to component and pass these values to super(), what do?

Comment: A way to solve this is to just inject `Injector` into base and derived classes. Using this injector in the base constructor we can say `this.firstService = injector.get(FirstService)`. Furthermore there might be a way to abstract the injecting of the `Injector` away to make the inheritance even easier. cheers

Comment: Cool, thanks for this suggestion. I've gone with this for now. The main thing for me was to remove the need to edit multiple files when I should only need to edit 1. This should do the trick. Thanks again.